# Слияние категорий и подкатегорий

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Добрый день.

Есть таблица типа:

```
CREATE TABLE categories
    (`id` int, `pid` int, `name` varchar(35),
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
;

INSERT INTO categories
    (`id`, `pid`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 0, 'a1'),
    (2, 0, 'a2'),
    (3, 0, 'a3'),
    (4, 0, 'a4'),
    (5, 0, 'a5'),
    (6, 3, 'a6'),
    (7, 3, 'a7'),
    (8, 5, 'a8'),
    (9, 5, 'a9')
;
```

Где:
**id** - идентификатор категории,
**pid** - идентификатор родительской категории,
**name** - наименование категории.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать запрос, чтобы получилось так:

```
|          id |                           path |
|-------------|--------------------------------|
|           1 |                             a1 |
|           2 |                             a2 |
|           3 |                             a3 |
|           4 |                             a4 |
|           5 |                             a5 |
|           6 |                        a3 > a6 |
|           7 |                        a3 > a7 |
|           8 |                        a5 > a8 |
|           9 |                        a5 > a9 |
```

Больше одного вложения быть не может.

Comment: Path это имя родительской категории + имя дочерней категории через разделитель ">"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, 
  CASE
    WHEN pid=0 THEN id
    ELSE CONCAT(pid, ' > ', id)
  END AS path 
FROM categories;
```

**Update:** Чтобы конкатенировать достать имена родителей нужен будет только `LEFT JOIN` с самой таблицей.

```
SELECT c.id,
  CASE
    WHEN c.pid=0 THEN c.name
    ELSE CONCAT(pc.name, ' > ', c.name)
  END AS path
FROM categories AS c LEFT JOIN categories AS pc ON c.pid=pc.id;
```

Comment: Нужно конкатенировать имена категорий.

Comment: @fedor-sg, обновил.

Comment: Ага, супер. То что надо. Спасибо.